# «Decora o que mais te diz» — how does this sentence work?

Tags: significado, sintaxe

I'm struggling to understand the bit in boldface below:

> Pouco a pouco, palavra a palavra, que sintas o meu afecto por escrito se não o sentires por de mais [...] **Decora o que te mais te diz, meu bem, e logo te darei mais que decorares**...

My best guess is something like, 'more than describe to you, baby, and soon I'll give you more than descriptions',

But clearly there is some grammatical construction going on in the first half that I'm not getting... Can anyone explain to me the meaning and the structure here?

Edit:

Based on comments, in this context, let us assume 'Decora' means 'memorize'. We'll presume the extra 'te' in the beginning is a typo. But how does the 'o que' part of the sentence work?

Comment: It sounds wrong to my ears.  Without more context.it's hard to understand what you mean.  "decora o que te mais te diz"... two personal pronouns (objective pronouns) .... te....te..... a typo?   Could it be "decora o que mais te digo e logo te darei mais para decorares"?

Comment: This expression is ambiguous and it's impossible to answer your question without the context. Decorar can be "to adorn" or "to memorize". We need more context to understand to which one are this sentence refers to.

Comment: The first bit is clearly wrong. There's one ***te*** too many: it could be «decora o que mais te diz» or «decora o que te mais diz» (*decorate/memorise that which is more meaningful to you/you relate more to*). Or it could be something like «decora o que teu mestre te diz» (*memorize what your teacher/master tells you*). And yes, more context would help. And the source too.

Comment: to know it could mean 'to memorize' is very helpful, given the context. I had assumed that the extra pronoun just meant something I didn't understand (spanish has some unusual-seeming [to an english speaker] usages of pronouns), but I guess I'll assume it was a typo. The author of it was a native portuguese (from portual) speaker, so I had assume dit wouldn't be a mistake.

Comment: Hi Kyle, can you give us the author and title, and expand the quote? I googled up the sentence, but Google found nothing.

Comment: @Jacinto, you won't find the source on Google... I know the author personally, if you catch my drift. I have expanded the quote above. Specfically, it was in response to a message that mentioned 'memorizing every word', so I am quite confident in the translation of 'Decora/decorares' now.

Comment: Some famous Brazilian writers have a peculiar way of writing that makes some sentences extremely hard to understand even to native Portuguese speakers, it seems to me you picked one of those. This is neither formal or informal way of speaking anywhere, and might require some familiarity with the work of this author to understand the message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have one ***te*** too many. We can delete either. I think *que mais te diz* is how most people would put it nowadays; so I’ll leave the *que te mais diz*, which has a quaint, 19th century feel to me, in keep with the rest of the sentence, I think:

> Decora o que te mais diz, meu bem, e logo te darei mais que decorares...

This translates as:

> Memorise that which you most relate to, my love, and then I’ll give you more to memorise.

Now the ***o que*** you stumbled on. You on can translate it simply as *what*, as in:

> Faz o que quiseres (*do what you want*)
> Come o que mais gostares (*eat what you like best*)
> Diz o que tens a dizer (*say what you have to say*)

But we can look at the two words. The *que* is the relative pronoun equivalent to *that*, *which*, or sometimes to *who*, as in:

> A carta ***que*** chegou hoje (*the letter **that** arrived today*)
> O carro ***que*** eu vi (*the car **that** I saw*)

The ***o*** is here a demonstrative pronoun [(Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/o) equivalent to *aquilo*; so *that*. So the whole thing is *memorise that that means most to you*. I wrote *that which* to avoid repeating *that*. Or you could say *memorise what means most to you*.

In the second bit — *te darei **mais que decorares*** — is rather unusual. I would say *mais que decorar*, not *decorares*. This *que*, is a relative pronoun without antecedent: it does not refer to anything mentioned earlier, unlike its cousin in *a carta **que** chegou hoje*. It is equivalent to *coisas que, algo que*: so *que decorar* = *coisas que decorar*. This construction was more common in the past, but I’ve never seen it with the personal infinitive (as *decorares*); always with the straight infinitive (as *decorar*). Nowadays people would more commonly say *mais para decorares*, which more closely matches the English *more to memorise*.

You had interpreted this bit, *mais que*, as *more than*. Well maybe that’s what was intended, and the author didn’t get it quite right. Maybe they meant to say *mais (do) que coisas que decorar*.

On a final note, the verb *dizer* — *o que te mais **diz*** —  is being used idiomatically in the sense of [(Aulete 11):](http://www.aulete.com.br/dizer)

> Provocar interesse, atração; ter significação para (alguém). [tdi. + a, para : *Esse lugar lhe diz alguma coisa?*]
>
> [my translation:] To raise interest, cause attraction; to have meaning to (someone) [ […] *Does this place attract/interest you in any way? Do you relate to this place in any way?*]

So, memorise the words that mean the most to you, and soon you’ll have more. Lucky you!

Comment: You didn't address the second part. "te darei mais que decorares" is quite a strange construction to me. I would say "te darei mais **para** decorar(es)". The most similar example with _que_ would require _ter_ or _haver_: "haverá mais que decorar", "terás mais que decorar"

Comment: @Artefacto I was hoping to get away without tackling it. It looks strange to me too. You find things like *dar que comer*, but always with the straight infinitive. A bit old fashioned, I think. Except for the somewhat fossilised *dar que fazer*.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you. Out of curiousity, is your background more Brazilian Portuguese, perhaps? (Trying to think of why the constructions would seem strange.) || 

I don't know your familiarity with Spanish, but it seems to me that 'o que' is essentially identical to 'lo que' in spanish (e.g., 'haz lo que quieras' -> 'do what you want') || 

There is the idiom in English, 'it speaks to me', e.g. in reference to an art piece that one feels emotion from. Would we say the usage of 'o que te mais diz' here is essentially 'that which speaks most to you'?

Comment: @KyleBaker It's only the second bit -- te darei **mais que decorares** -- that sounds strange (I was replying to Artefacto). I've only ever seen things like **darei mais que decorar**, not **decorares**.; *darei mais que decorar* sounds only a bit 19th century to me. Nowadays you'd say *darei mas **para** decorar* or *darei mais para decorares*.